# prefer result external ID using C# GNSDK

Tags: c#, windows-phone, gracenote

Using the sample app provided in the GNSDK for windows phone, I can match mic input to tracks just fine. I want to retrieve track IDs from 3rd party metadata; I cannot find it.

I modified the app as follows:

```
App.gnMusicIDStream_.Options.LookupData(GnLookupData.kLookupDataExternalIds, true);
App.gnMusicIDStream_.Options.PreferResultExternalId("[third party id which works for me using android or ios versions of GN]");
```

[...]

```
GnExternalId[] trackIds = result.Albums.First().TracksMatched.First().ExternalIds.ToArray();
```

Tests only returned irrelevant externalIds like the following:

source: deezer-track-id

value: 13913080

Am I setting up all the config steps required? Am I looking for the returned external IDs for matched tracks correctly?

Answer (score 1):

What you did is right, it's just that Deezer ID's are currently the only types of external ID's available for free, non-commercial API access. Other external ID's require a commercial license.